# Show a websites' latest blog post on the search results page

Tags: wordpress

My main idea is that when i do a google search on my company's info, it keeps showing the latest post made. I would like to make the info the same everytime i do a google search. That will definitely show a good image of my company.  I am using wordpress to run my company's website. I need some guidance on this... Thanks... Please pardon me if this is a stupid question. If there is other ways of doing this, instead of using wordpress, do tell me... Will be very happy to hear some suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question, and I think that there are a couple ways you could do it.

The first way that came to mind is to use your site's [meta description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element) on your home page. Your meta description is the 156 characters that appear in black letters underneath your site title in the search results.

[image: meta description example SERP]

If you want your meta description to be static and unchanging, just like LinkedIn, you can set your meta description without any coding knowledge using [Yoast's Wordpress SEO Plugin](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/). After you install it, edit your home page in Wordpress Admin and set the meta description to be your desired text. You can set the meta description for every page on your site, and each one will display the corresponding description in the search results.

If you want your meta description to be the latest post, you will either need to change the meta description for the homepage manually every time you write a new post, or you could write up some code to automatically generate the meta description from the first 156 characters of your latest blog post.

But, there is a second method that might work better. For an example site, I did a Google search for CSSTricks.com. Notice that it appears that Google is automatically pulling in their latest post without them having to do any hoopla with the meta description.

[image: no meta description example SERP]

So, I went to CSSTricks using Google Chrome and did a right-click -> Inspect Element to view the source of the web page, to see how they were doing it. (You may need to open the below image in a new tab or save it to your computer to be able to read the code, because it is so small)

[image: example of page with source code]

They do not have any meta description on their site, but they are using the [HTML5 article tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_article.asp). It appears that Google is pulling in the first p tag nested inside the article tag, and then displaying that as the black text in place of the meta description. So theoretically, if this is indeed how it works, what you need to do is write the markup of your home page so that it displays the post content using the article tag with a nested p tag, just as they have done.

Hope this helps!